# Как динамично добавлять вьюшки в OAStackView?

Tags: ios, swift4

В приложении пользователь может прикрепить на форму несколько файлов. Для этого использовал `UIImagePickerController`:

```
@IBAction func AttachNewFileClick(_ sender: Any) {
    let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let imageUrl:URL = info["UIImagePickerControllerImageURL"] as! URL
    let mime:String = info["UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"] as! String
    let original:UIImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as! UIImage
    let newAttachedFile = AttachedPhoto()
    newAttachedFile.setImageSource(url: imageUrl, name: imageUrl.lastPathComponent, mime: mime, image: original)
    AttachedFilesStack.addSubview(newAttachedFile)
    filePreview.append(newAttachedFile)
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Прикрепленные файлы - объекты класса `AttachedPhoto`. В нем есть UIImageView и UIButton для открепления вложения. Все превью вложенных фото лежать в `AttachedFilesStack` который является объектом класса OAStackView (min SDK 8.2, поэтому я не могу использовать встроенные StackView, для них нужно min SDK 9).

Первое вложение показывается корректно, но последующие вместо того чтобы располагаться рядом перекрывают первое. Что я могу сделать чтобы исправить это поведение?

Нет вложений:

[image: No image attached]

Прикреплено первое фото:

[image: First image selected]

Прикреплено второе (с первым все в порядке, оно просто перекрыто вторым):

[image: Second image selected]

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать вместо `addSubview` метод `addArrangedSubview`.